# Displaying JSON specific JSON result in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm new with Python and have the following code:

```
def doSentimentAnalysisAndPrint(keyval):  
    import urllib

    data = urllib.urlencode(keyval) 
    u = urllib.urlopen("http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/", data)
    json_string = u.read()   

    parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)

    # print the various key:values
    print(parsed_json['probability'])
    print ">>", parsed_json['label']
```

The printed result is:

```
{u'neg': 0.24087437946650492, u'neutral': 0.19184084028194423, u'pos': 0.7591256205334951}
>> pos
```

I would like to only print out the actual result? E.G. in this case "Positive: 0.7591256205334951" but don't know how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean with "the actual result"? Do you mean using `parsed_json['label']['pos']`?

Comment: Yes I want to print out the highest value returned?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker `parsed_json['label']` return `pos` OP mean `parsed_json['probability']['pos']`

Comment: Right, so in some cases `neutral` can be higher, in which case you want *that* value?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: I'm going to assume that `parsed_json['label']` would be set to `'neutral'` in that case.

Comment: Either neutral, negative or positive can be higher depending on the result?

Comment: The [API documentation](http://text-processing.com/docs/sentiment.html) comfirms my assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do read the [API documentation](http://text-processing.com/docs/sentiment.html) when using one. The `'label'` key points to what key in the `'probability'` dictionary is the determined sentiment:

> **label:** will be either `pos` if the text is determined to be *positive*, `neg` if the text is *negative*, or `neutral` if the text is neither `pos` nor `neg`.
>
> **probability:** an object that contains the probability for each label. `neg` and `pos` will add up to 1, while `neutral` is standalone. If `neutral` is greater than `0.5` then the `label` will be `neutral`. Otherwise, the `label` will be `pos` or `neg`, whichever has the greater probability.

So you already have a label, and the corresponding value is just a key lookup. Map the label values to a string to print (like `pos` mapping to `Positive`, and combine the two:

```
sentiments = {'pos': 'Positive', 'neg': 'Negative', 'neutral': 'Neutral'}
label = parsed_json['label']
print sentiments[label], parsed_json['probability'][label]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help thats exactly what I wanted.